# How to override form id of Webform?

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms

I want to override form_id of webform in Drupal 7. Example my webform form id is `webform_141` and I want to override it to `webform_en` or `webform_uk`.

Is it possible?

**Note**: I need to override it for multilingual site.

Comment: What is the reason to override the form ID?

Comment: @JimmyKo I need to override it for multilingual site.

Comment: I think changing form ID is discouraged and there is no safe way to do that. You have never know how other module manipulates the form ID. If you change it to ease the development. I would suggest you to store the form ID into a constant or inside the $conf array in settings.php

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do following way, using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x), paste following code in your `template.php` file, save and clear cache. Change the THEME with your themeName in code or if you are doing with costume module then with module name.

In your case the code will be,

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_141') {
    $form['#id'] = 'webform_en';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x).

E.g:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_from_alter
 * 
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @param type $form_id
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['#form_id']='webform_en';
}
```

Comment: When you see the form in console then id will be the same(its default one).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implement hook_from_alter
 * 
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @param type $form_id`enter code here`
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {                                           
   if($form_id == 'webform_141'){
    $form['#form_id'] = 'webform_en';
    $form['#form_id'] = 'webform-en';
    $form['form_id']['#value'] = 'webform_en';
    $form['form_id']['#id'] = 'webform_en';
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably should add an if statement checking the form ID as shown in [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222449/how-to-override-form-id-of-webform-in-drupal-7#answer-222459), other wise, **all** of your forms will be affected.